# ListView и android:autoLink="phone"

Tags: android

В моем `ListView` отображаются заказы, номера мобильных подсвечиваются, но вместе с ними подсвечиваются и даты и цены. Вот как это выглядит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вопрос:  можно ли как то, какими то фильтрами указать что номер телефона может быть только после слова `Тел.`, ну или как то по-другому. И если нет, то каким образом можно в один `Item` для `ListView` вставить два или три `TextViev`, чтобы я мог разделить основную инфу о заказе и номер телефона, что бы избежать подсвечивания ненужных строк?

Comment: создайте кастомный элемент списка, и сделайте `android:autoLink=“phone”` только для того `TextView`, Где телефон

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у Вас ListView состоит из одного текстового поля, и при клике на элемент необходимо совершить звонок. То можно пойти двумя путями:
1) Костыльный метод. Это при условии, что все элементы будут идентичны другим.

```
String text = yourTextViewArray.get(i).getText().toString();//достаем из onItemClickLister-a
text.getText()..substring(text.indexOf("Тел. ") + 5, text.indexOf("Дата"))
```

Как-то так. Надо поиграться.

2) Правильный вариант. Надо создать объект, типа такого:

```
public class Client {

    private String order;
    private String name;
    private String phone;
    private String date;

    public String getOrder() {
        return order;
    }

    public void setOrder(String order) {
        this.order = order;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }
}
```

Для вашего адаптера используйте `ArrayList<Client>`. Как создать кастомный адаптер - нагуглите. Через xml, тоже всё грамотно отрисуете, как должен выглядеть ваш итем. И уже при клике `listview` будете брать `clients.getPosition(position).getPhone()`;

Comment: @Андроид Андроид Я примерно так и делаю. У меня есть List<Orders> из которого я достаю все даннные включая Номер, дату, имя  и делаю одну строку со всей инфой дописав туда "Тел." , "Имя: "  и тд. Проблема у меня в том месте где я в одни Item( TextView ) кладу строку со всей инфой из-за чего у меня подсвечивается ссылкой не только номер но и дата. Мне интересно как можно создать Item из 2-3 TextViev с разными свойствами, но так что бы они выклядели по преждему как один Item.

Comment: @KirillStoianov Через xml Вы можете подчеркнуть нужный вам textview в элементе списка(гуглите: android textview underline), а также в адаптере навесить слушатель onClickListener, для каждого текстового поля со своими функциями.